# How to send GTM event after sign in with Auth0 hooks?

Tags: reactjs, google-tag-manager, auth0, react-gtm-module

We have a react app with react-Auth0 for authentification using the hook `loginWithRedirect`.

```
  const { user, isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect, logout } = useAuth0();
```

We want to send a custom GTM (Google Tag Manager) event with Sign-in method and userID received from Auth0, but I got no way of triggering the event as the Hooks use with Auth0 is self contain.

Using useEffect on user objet will trigger the GTM event everytime someone land on the page:

```
   useEffect(() => {
    const tagManagerArgs = {
      dataLayer: {
        userEmail: user.email,
        userProject: 'project',
        event: 'login'
      },
      dataLayerName: 'PageDataLayer'
    }
    TagManager.dataLayer(tagManagerArgs)
  }, [user]);
```

How can we detect login event ? and not send a GTM event everytime someone refresh the page ?